# filling out an added column with data from another table

Tags: mysql

Hind sight is 20-20 and now I'm paying the price. When I first set this up, this info wasn't needed but now it is so I'm back tracking.

- 2 tables in database (sites [id, site], visitNotes [site])
- sites.site populated visitNotes.site
- Now they want a list of sites that ran alarm tests in the last month which is on the visitNotes table, but there's no way of telling which sites did not get checked since there's no recording

What I've done

- Added a column visitNotes.siteid

What I want to do

- **Have the database populate the visitNotes.siteid column with sites.id info**
- So it should look at visitNotes.site-->match it with sites.site--> get the corrosponding sites.id-->put it in visitNotes.siteid

sites table [id, site]

"1" "Lawton Acres"

"2" "AMBLE"

"3" "ASHWOOD"

"4" "BACHMAN"

"5" "Bennett"

"6" "Birchwood"

visitNotes table [id, timestamp, uniqueid, date, siteid **(what I want filled out)**, site, groupid]

"7620"  "6/6/2018 08:07:14" "5b17f0d541017" "5/31/2018" ""  "Stateline West"    "18hprw3"

"7621"  "6/6/2018 08:08:51" "5b17f0d541017" "5/31/2018" ""  "Stateline East"    "18Can6"

"7622"  "6/6/2018 08:12:30" "5b17f0d541017" "5/30/2018" ""  "Basswood"  "18Sp4"

"7623"  "6/6/2018 08:14:23" "5b17f0d541017" "5/30/2018" ""  "JMG"   "18C8"

"7624"  "6/6/2018 08:14:24" "5b17f0d541017" "5/30/2018" ""  "JMG"   "18C8"

"7625"  "6/6/2018 08:15:14" "5b17f0d541017" "5/30/2018" ""  "JMG"   "18C8"

"7626"  "6/6/2018 08:46:09" "5b180156327d5" "6/6/2018"  ""  "HWY 14"    "18hprw9"

"7627"  "6/6/2018 10:18:29" "5b1817189adf5" "6/6/2018"  ""  "Powersville"   "18hprw13"

"7628"  "6/6/2018 13:25:13" "5b184180dfb16" "6/6/2018"  ""  "Friesen 1" "18D12"

"7629"  "6/6/2018 13:26:55" "5b184360d2878" "6/6/2018"  ""  "Friesen 3" ""

"7630"  "6/6/2018 13:27:53" "5b184393919e7" "6/6/2018"  ""  "Irvin" ""

Inner Join? I've tried tons of different things but none seem to work. Can someone help me figure out how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You should ideally show your data and expected result, and the SQL query  you already tried

Comment: anyone? I've added more.....????